# Any guarantee that replacing the ATI graphic chip works

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, laptop-repair

Im having a Dell studio 1558 laptop that was purchased 4 yrs ago and now im having a problem in booting the laptop.I gave it to a service center and they said some problem with ATI graphic chip and either I need to replace the motherboard or they can replace the graphic chip alone with 3 months warranty. Which one I should go for? Is there any guarantee that replacing motherboard/graphic chip work for some years?